# Lat, Long & RSSI to 3D figure

Tags: python, csv, 3d, gps, pyproj

I've been trying to combine lat & long coordinates with wifi RSSI value from wardriving data sets to get a 3D mesh - [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWNPa.png).  So to have: `X,Y,Z = Lat, Long, RSSI`

So far I have exported the X,Y,Z to a CSV file and tried to import it to blender using [this](https://blenderartists.org/t/a-script-to-import-a-csv-file-and-create-meshes-for-blender-2-5x-or-later/501410) script, but not getting anything useful. Mostly just straight lines.

I have also tried to convert the Lat & Long to ecef with pyproj to have the RSSI and gps data be more alike, but to no avail.

My CSV looks like this:

```
[(84.93475847252022, -89.91906774534704, -72.0)
 (84.93444026890381, -89.9190789918068, -78.0)
 (84.93447718347761, -89.91908064130264, -79.0)
 (84.93446626538486, -89.9190807252239, -79.0)
 (84.93464567138756, -89.91907317821823, -75.0)
 (84.93475424916566, -89.91908073758599, -79.0)
 (84.93485534408349, -89.91909018237004, -84.0)
 (84.93493336837452, -89.9190845795334, -81.0)]
```

Comment: why do you need to show height? can't you just use the RSSI value as a color value?

Comment: I'm looking to visualize the wifi signal strength as geography. If it was part of the landscape. And if I used a color value it would remain flat.

Answer (score 2):

```
import folium

import pandas as pd

from folium import plugins

SF_COORDINATES = (84.9347, -89.9190)
```

> Import Packages and Find your coordinates online as shown above

```
MAX_RECORDS = 1000

map = folium.Map(location=SF_COORDINATES, zoom_start=20)

for index,row in data.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['Lat'], row['Lon']],
                        radius=5,
                        popup=row['Rssi'],
                        fill_color="#3db7e4",
                        clustered_marker = True).add_to(map)

arra = data[['lat', 'lon']].as_matrix()
map.add_children(plugins.HeatMap(arra, radius=25))
map
```

> The above code shall work with folium and pandas packages

Comment: Can you give me an example format of the "data" object?